# Inconsistent results using R httr POST command

Tags: post, httr

One of my colleagues has been scraping financial data using
Python.  He sent me a snippet of Python code as an example:

```
import requests
import bs4

response = requests.post('http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/voo/historical',
                         data='2y|false|VOO',
                         headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
table_data = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr('td')]
              for tr in html('tr')][1:]

print table_data[0]
print table_data[-1]
```

Here's an example of the output from the Python code:

```
$ python scrape-nasdaq.py
[u'16:00', u'206.21', u'207.27', u'205.95', u'206.74', u'2,983,048']
[u'12/08/2014', u'190.35', u'190.83', u'188.85', u'189.5', u'1,527,709']
```

This is supposed to download two years worth of stock data about a Vanguard
fund (chosen more or less at random, I presume), and it appears to do exactly
that.  (Note the "2014" string in the output.)

For some time I've had a passive interest in web scraping but have never had
occasion to try it seriously.  I took my colleague's code as a kind of
challenge and decided to try to emulate the Python code using the `httr`
package, which, IIUC, was inspired, in part, by the BeautifulSoup Python
package.

I tried to emulate as closely as possible the Python code, but I'm unable to
get the code to download the data.  A more-complete description is that
*sometimes* I can download *some* data, namely, the default, 3-month list of
data from the web site, but I can't get the web site to honor my request for
two years worth of data.  At other times I get only an error response:

```
> stop_for_status(result)
Error: Service Unavailable (HTTP 503).
```

On the "good" runs of the code I get a "200" response (but, as I said, don't
get all the requested data).  I don't have a clue as to why it works (at all)
some times and simply fails at other times.

Here's the R code and the results (for the case in which I get *some* data):

```
library (httr)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

base_url <- "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/voo/historical"

body     <- list(data="2y|false|VOO")
headers  <- '"Content-Type"="application/json"'

result <- POST(base_url,
               add_headers(headers),
               body = body,
               encode="json",
               verbose())
stop_for_status(result)

table_data <- content(result) %>%
    html_nodes("table")  %>%
    html_table(header=TRUE) %>%
    `[[`(1) %>%
    slice(2:n())

names(table_data) <- sapply(names(table_data), function(name) {
                            unlist(strsplit(name, '\r'))[1]})
names(table_data)
head(table_data)
tail(table_data)

> head(table_data)
        Date   Open    High     Low Close / Last    Volume
1 12/07/2016 203.45 206.320 203.300       206.20 2,253,230
2 12/06/2016 203.17 203.630 202.640       203.62 2,412,897
3 12/05/2016 202.64 203.300 202.415       202.91 2,070,675
4 12/02/2016 201.70 202.230 201.350       201.75 2,119,016
5 12/01/2016 202.68 202.710 201.240       201.61 3,281,407
6 11/30/2016 203.53 203.692 202.310       202.40 2,359,018

> tail(table_data)
         Date   Open     High    Low Close / Last    Volume
60 09/14/2016 194.83 196.1199 194.12       194.66 2,966,319
61 09/13/2016 196.25 196.5100 194.12       194.78 3,361,848
62 09/12/2016 194.88 198.9500 194.80       198.48 2,800,160
63 09/09/2016 199.08 199.1800 195.67       195.68 3,430,638
64 09/08/2016 200.62 200.9199 200.19       200.52 2,180,474
65 09/07/2016 200.82 201.1500 200.32       200.99 1,455,442
>
```

As you can see from the head/tail above, all of the results are confined to
the current day and the three preceding months.

Suggestions are welcome.  I've appended the verbose output of the POST
command, as well as my session info.

-- Michael

## Appendix 1: verbose output from the POST command

```
-> POST /symbol/voo/historical HTTP/1.1
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.35.0 r-curl/2.3 httr/1.2.1
-> Host: www.nasdaq.com
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: application/json
-> Content-Length: 23
-> 
>> {"data":"2y|false|VOO"}

<- HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
<- Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
<- Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
<- Content-Length: 326
<- Expires: Fri, 09 Dec 2016 01:58:03 GMT
<- Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
<- Pragma: no-cache
<- Date: Fri, 09 Dec 2016 01:58:03 GMT
<- Connection: close
<- Set-Cookie:
NSC_W.TJUFEFGFOEFS.OBTEBR.80=ffffffffc3a08e3045525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660;expires=Fri,
09-Dec-2016 02:08:03 GMT;path=/;httponly
<- 
> stop_for_status(result)
Error: Service Unavailable (HTTP 503).
>
```

## Appendix 2: session information

```
> session_info()
Session info
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
 ui       X11                         
 language en_US                       
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       <NA>                        
 date     2016-12-08                  

Packages
-------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version    date       source                          
 assertthat   0.1        2013-12-06 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                  
 colorspace   1.3-1      2016-11-18 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                  
 curl         2.3        2016-11-24 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                  
 DBI          0.5-1      2016-09-10 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                  
 devtools   * 1.12.0     2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                  
 digest       0.6.10     2016-08-02 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                  
 dplyr      * 0.5.0      2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                  
 ggplot2    * 2.2.0      2016-11-11 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                  
 gtable       0.2.0      2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.2.3)                  
 hms          0.3        2016-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                  
 httr       * 1.2.1      2016-07-03 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                  
 jsonlite     1.1        2016-09-14 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                  
 lazyeval     0.2.0      2016-06-12 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                  
 magrittr     1.5        2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                  
 memoise      1.0.0      2016-01-29 CRAN (R 3.2.3)                  
 munsell      0.4.3      2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.2.3)                  
 plyr         1.8.4      2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                  
 purrr      * 0.2.2      2016-06-18 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                  
 R6           2.2.0      2016-10-05 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                  
 Rcpp         0.12.8     2016-11-17 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                  
 readr      * 1.0.0.9000 2016-11-01 Github (tidyverse/readr@b8c3ddb)
 rvest      * 0.3.2      2016-06-17 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                  
 scales       0.4.1      2016-11-09 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                  
 tibble     * 1.2        2016-08-26 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                  
 tidyr      * 0.6.0      2016-08-12 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                  
 tidyverse  * 1.0.0      2016-09-09 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                  
 withr        1.0.2      2016-06-20 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                  
 xml2       * 1.0.0      2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.1)                  
>
```

## Re: Hadley's suggestion:

Thanks, Hadley.  I'm not sure how to do the comparison you suggest, but here's
my cut at it.

First from R:

```
result_text <- content(result, "text")
result_text <- unlist(strsplit(result_text, "\r\n"))
result_text[1:10]

> result_text[1:10]
 [1] "<div id=\"quotes_content_left_pnlAJAX\">"    "\t"                                         
 [3] "            <h3 class=\"table-headtag\">"    "                Results
for: 3 Month, From "
 [5] "09-SEP-2016  TO 09-DEC-2016 "                "            </h3>"                          
 [7] "            <table>"                         "                <thead>"                    
 [9] "                    <tr>"                    "
<th>Date</th>"
```

Now the Python:

```
In [21]: response.text[0:255]
Out[21]: u'<div id="quotes_content_left_pnlAJAX">\r\n\t\r\n            <h3
class="table-headtag">\r\n                Results for: 2 Years, From
\r\n09-DEC-2014  TO 09-DEC-2016 \r\n            </h3>\r\n
<table>\r\n                <thead>\r\n                    <tr>\r\n      '
```

So far as I can tell, these are the same except for the time interval.  My
only thought is that I've somehow botched the syntax of the "body" parameter,
and my time interval is, therefore, not getting communicated to the server.

## Same results from `curl`

This is undoubtedly not surprising, but I get the same results (only the
default, three-months worth of data) from the following `curl` code:

```
library(curl)
h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(h, copypostfields = "data='2y|false|VOO'")
handle_setheaders(h,
                  "Content-Type"="application/json"
                  )
result <- curl_fetch_memory(base_url, handle = h)
```

Comment: I'd recommend comparing the request that httr generates to the request that requests generates.

Answer (score 0):

Following a suggestion from Duncan Temple Lang, I've been able to download
data "as advertised".  Here's revised code, which shows two methods of
downloading (i.e., `httr` and `RCurl`):

```
library (httr)

setup_query <- function(symbol, time_interval) {

    base_url <- paste("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/",
                      tolower(symbol),
                      "/historical",
                      sep='')

    data_string <- paste(time_interval, "|false|", symbol, sep='')

    body <- c("data"=data_string)
    headers <- c("Content-Type" = "application/json")

    list(url=base_url, body=body, headers=headers)
}

get_table_data <- function(doc) {
    doc %>%
        read_html() %>%
        html_nodes("table")  %>%
        html_table(header=TRUE) %>%
        `[[`(1) %>%
        slice(2:n()) -> table_data

    names(table_data) <- sapply(names(table_data), function(name) {
        unlist(strsplit(name, '\r'))[1]})
    return(table_data)
}

query_params <- setup_query("VOO", "1y")

result_h <- POST(query_params$url,
                 add_headers(.headers=query_params$headers),
                 body = query_params$body,
                 encode="json",
                 verbose())

stop_for_status(result_h)


library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

table_data_h <- get_table_data(result_h)

head(table_data_h)
tail(table_data_h)


#### Duncan, 2017-03-07

library(RCurl)

query_params <- setup_query("VOO", "2y")

result_d = getURLContent(query_params$url,
                         postfields = as.character(query_params$body),
                         httpheader = query_params$headers,
                         customrequest = "POST")


table_data_d <- get_table_data(result_d)

head(table_data_d)
tail(table_data_d)
```

And here are the results from a run of the code today.  Note that I chose two
different time intervals to highlight the differences.

```
> head(table_data_h)
        Date   Open    High      Low Close / Last    Volume
1 03/09/2017 217.33 217.836 216.4602       217.41 1,634,713
2 03/08/2017 217.95 218.200 217.0700       217.18 1,784,348
3 03/07/2017 217.98 218.330 217.4200       217.64 1,742,746
4 03/06/2017 218.07 218.648 217.6300       218.30 1,530,987
5 03/03/2017 218.70 219.090 218.3080       218.98 1,765,450
6 03/02/2017 219.99 220.020 218.7500       218.86 1,650,637

> tail(table_data_h)
          Date   Open   High    Low Close / Last    Volume
248 03/16/2016 184.88 186.93 184.86       186.57 2,700,654
249 03/15/2016 184.70 185.46 184.42       185.46 1,325,297
250 03/14/2016 185.40 186.20 185.07       185.70 1,412,806
251 03/11/2016 184.57 186.01 184.46       185.98 2,231,094
252 03/10/2016 183.38 184.39 181.03       183.01 2,089,526
253 03/09/2016 182.85 183.22 182.01       182.91 1,641,079

> head(table_data_d)
        Date   Open    High      Low Close / Last    Volume
1 03/09/2017 217.33 217.836 216.4602       217.41 1,634,713
2 03/08/2017 217.95 218.200 217.0700       217.18 1,784,348
3 03/07/2017 217.98 218.330 217.4200       217.64 1,742,746
4 03/06/2017 218.07 218.648 217.6300       218.30 1,530,987
5 03/03/2017 218.70 219.090 218.3080       218.98 1,765,450
6 03/02/2017 219.99 220.020 218.7500       218.86 1,650,637

> tail(table_data_d)
          Date   Open    High    Low Close / Last    Volume
501 03/16/2015 189.59 191.380 189.55       191.38 1,054,150
502 03/13/2015 189.68 189.790 187.62       188.80 1,792,236
503 03/12/2015 188.21 190.000 188.20       189.96 2,313,157
504 03/11/2015 188.26 188.470 187.47       187.54 1,857,393
505 03/10/2015 189.57 189.632 187.97       187.98 2,390,401
506 03/09/2015 190.52 191.470 190.42       191.12 1,131,634
>
```